# Emma : After instrumenting, test cases fail

Tags: eclipse, junit, ant, emma

I have two legacy ANT projects one in the FrontEnd Server and the other in BackEnd Server. Both servers runs on JBoss and the communication between the servers is through Web Services. I have instrumented my test class and other classes which I will be testing from the Junit.

When I run the test cases, all of them are failing and the error stack trace shows "Could not initialize class com.xyz.123.classNameImpl". Any suggestions is appreciated.

Note : I have added emma.jar in the build path. 
java version : jdk 7
Eclipse version : Indigo
Build tool : ANT

Comment: If  code cover has been newly added or the error occurred with Java 7 now, try [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/index.html) instead of Emma. (JaCoCo can be seen as a successor of Emma.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please let me know how to do offline instrumentation ( cmd line)  using JaCoCo as it is little difficult to understand the documentation page.

Comment: See: JaCoCo > Documentation > [Ant Tasks](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html)